# TCP Socket Android Client

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a problem with a android socket client. I try to send a string from an android client to a python server. I create a test app in netbeans and the code its working, but on android doesn't work. I verify if data comes to server with print of string on server.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.tcp_button;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
                Socket socket = null;    

                try {
                    socket = new Socket("192.168.0.106", 5555);
                    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("on"); 
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });

    }

}
```

here is the log :

```
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.example.tcp_button.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:142)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-27 20:38:49.388: E/AndroidRuntime(2367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is your android device on the 192.168.0.106 local (wifi?) network?  Do you see anything in logcat?

Comment: I tested both variants and still not working.

Comment: i have my android device connected to local network via wifi

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try making the `Socket` this way:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);

// Use this just in case you have to read from the server
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

// This will be used to send to the server
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write("This is my message".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

**---- EDIT ----**

After seeing your update, your code has nothing to do with it. Your problem is *where* have you put this piece of code, as Android forbids placing any network operation in the main UI because it would block the interface with the user, resulting in a very poor user experience and probably the user will uninstall your app.

You have to place that code within a `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`. If you're starting with it, you probably want to try with the latter. Here's a [nice example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html).

Comment: I have the same result. I just post the log

Comment: Updated my answer too.

Comment: Done. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing the outputstream:

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("on"); 
dataOutputStream.flush();
```

You also might want to close it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is `StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork` of your Logcat. Try to add:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

inside `onCreate()` and before `addListenerOnButton()`. It is also a good idea to double check AndroidManifest.xml for granted permissions.